# Separate dataframe into two columns by comma python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

need some help on this - I think this isn't too difficult but having a mental block.
I am trying to convert the dataframe with one column into two and separate it by a comma. Below is the code I am using:

```
log_model2coeff_df = log_model2coeff_df['lol'].apply(lambda x :pd.Series(x.split(',')))


+-----------------------------------------------+
|                      lol                      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| ('Principal', array([-0.00088419]))           |
| ('age', array([ 0.01724407]))                 |
| ('Male', array([-0.31822202]))                |
| ('High School or Below', array([-0.0003084])) |
| ('Master or Above', array([ 0.02205005]))     |
| ('college', array([ 0.10759677]))             |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I want it to look like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|        lol                |         lol2          |                                                           
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ('college'              |  array([ 0.10759677]))  |
| ('age'                  |  array([ 0.01724407]))  |
| ('Principal'            |  array([-0.00088419]))  |
| ('Master or Above'      |  array([ 0.02205005]))  |
| ('Male'                 |  array([-0.31822202]))  |
| ('High School or Below' |  array([-0.0003084]))   |
+----------------------------------------------------


Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to store the result of the split in an intermediate variable.

```
split = df['lol'].str.split(',')
df['lol'] = split.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['lol2'] = split.apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Hi csander, thanks for your quicky reply! However, the code seems to give an error saying: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Does your column `lol` already contain tuples? I assumed it had strings that you were splitting on the comma character, but that wouldn't really make sense because you are getting objects rather than strings from the split.